# Bash variables and outputs

Tags: bash

```
grep -A 26 "some text" somefile.txt |
awk '/other text/ { gsub(/M/, " "); print $4 }' | while read line
do
   //operations resulting in a true of false answer
done
```

The variables declared and used in the while only exist with the sub-shell created by piping to it, how do I keep track of them from outside? I need to use the returned true or false later in the script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use process substitution:

```
while read line
do
   # operations resulting in a true of false answer
done < <(grep -A 26 "some text" somefile.txt | \
         awk '/other text/ { gsub(/M/, " "); print $4 }' )
```

Comment: Damn, I was just posting essentially the same. You beat me ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `bash` 4.2 or later, set the `lastpipe` option. This forces the last command in a pipeline (in this case, your while loop) to run in the current shell instead of a subshell, so any modifications to variables you make in the loop remain visible after it completes.